# National Congressional Districts vector tileset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa

Is there a vector tile set available online somewhere of US national congressional districts? I have been downloading shapefiles from the US Census bureau's shapefile repository, converting these to json with mapshaper.org and then converting to tile sets with MapTiler desktop. It would be way simpler to just find an existing prebuilt protobuf file online. It is generic data, so just figuring it may exist somewhere. Where should I look? No luck with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have to build your own tilesets.  You can also use QGIS and automate it.

Comment: can you provide more information regarding this process please.